# RegEx for Matching Numeric Patterns With or Without Dashes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Are Email Host has a back end Archiving platform. I asked them if we could be alerted if certain formats are located within the Email and they asked me to submit them a RegEx Query String so they can put it into there system. I Know there Main Email System is Exchange, how ever I am not sure what there backend is.... I am assuming exchange and I apologize for I did not even think to ask for that piece of info.

NEED TO LOOK FOR THE FOLLOWING DIGIT PATTERNS (which is for Social Security # Formats)

9 digit formats:

XXX-XX-XXXX

XXXXXXXXX

XX-XXXXXXX

NEED TO LOOK FOR THE FOLLOWING DIGIT PATTERNS (which is for Customer Acct # Formats)

8 digit formats:

xxxxxxxx

I have not tried anything for I am not sure on how to test with out submitting to my host. But this is what I cam up with Two stings to accomplish the task for both 8 and 9 digit patterns

```
Regex.Match([/d]+[/d]+\-?[/d]+\-?[/d]+[/d-]+\-?[/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]);
``
Regex.Match([/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]+[/d]);
```

I would expect the output to be any email that matches the numeric sequence pattern

Answer (score 1):

Just for simplicity, you might want to design an easy expression, maybe something similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/qXTzHS/1/), to be easy to be changed whenever you wish:

```
([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{8})
```

It has four groups for each of your numbers:

- `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})` for SSN type 1
- `([0-9]{9})` for SSN type 2
- `([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})` for SSN type 3

---

- `([0-9]{8})` which is for customer account number

You can simply join this groups with an OR:

```
([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{8})
```

If you wish to have two separate expressions, you might want to join the first two:

```
([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})
```

and your second expression would work as:

```
([0-9]{8})
```

---

You can add additional boundaries to it if you wish. For example, you can bound them with start and end chars:

#### Both RegEx:

```
^([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{8})$
```

#### SSN RegEx:

```
^([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})$
```

#### Customer Account RegEx:

```
^([0-9]{8})$
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Testing

```js
const regex = /([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{8})/gm;
const str = `111-22-3333
111223333
11-1234567
12345678`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: WOW These are all such great answers and HELP I Really APPRACIATE the in debth answers posted here and the simple corrections on what type of slash to use.... I think one of these or a combination of them will get me to my end results..... I will post again after I have it working or get stuck LoL

Comment: I would love to know how you created that java test area in your post.... For I would like to test this one which is basically the same as I posted but ads spaces and periods to the syntex search

Comment: (\d\d\d((\s|.|-|\)|\)\s)\d\d(\s|.|-)\d\d\d\d|([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{8})

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following regex pattern, which is an alternation of three terms:

```
\d{8}\d?|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{7}
```

### Demo

Note that a single digit in regex is represented by `\d`, with a single *backslash*, not a forward slash.